# how to delete an item using filter() (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

I would like to delete an item from an item list using `filter()` .
The function to delete the item is in a parent component that I then call in a child component.

here is the function of the parents component:

```
deletePlayer = (id) => {
    const teamPlayers = this.state.teamPlayers
    teamPlayers.filter(i => i.idTeam !== id)

    console.log('my players: ', teamPlayers);  
}
```

I pass this function in props:

```
  <//other props...
   strNationality={player.strNationality}
   deletePlayer={(id) => this.deletePlayer(id)}
 /> 
))
```

I get it from my child:

```
 deletItem  = (e, id) => {
     console.log('mes propos player: ', this.props.idPlayer);
     this.props.deletePlayer(id)
 }
```

and this is how I trigger the event:

```
  <Button 
    onClick={ () => this.deletItem(this.props.idPlayer) } 
    className='button' 
    color='black' 
    type='submit'>
```

I get the right id but `filter()` never filters and it finds all my objects. It's like he's ignoring the **!== id**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This line is a problem:

```
teamPlayers.filter(i => i.idTeam !== id)
```

`filter` returns a *new* array once the iterations are complete, it doesn't do the filtering in place. You need to assign that filtered array to a new variable. Since `filter` doesn't mutate the original state array you can just run the process on that to get the new filtered array which you can then log to the console.

```
const teamPlayers = this.state.teamPlayers.filter(i => i.idTeam !== id));
console.log('my players: ', teamPlayers);
```

Comment: nope , I tried, I have the log since my child of the good id but filter returns me a table with this item in it

Comment: Is `idTeam` in the state an integer or a string? The value from the component is a string so you may have to cast it to a different type.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but within the react context you can do this:

```
  deletePlayer = id => {
    this.setState({
      teamPlayers: this.state.teamPlayers.filter(
        player => player.idTeam !== id,
      ),
    });
  };
```

The issue is that you are not updating the state using setState...

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the state of the teamPlayers , if you are using a functional component and useState , then I would recommend this.

```
deletePlayer = (id) => {
    
    setTeamPlayers(prevTeamPlayers =>prevTeamPlayers.filter(teamPlayer => teamPlayer.idTeam !== id))

  
}
```